# Wordpress inline SVG won't display, does display in visual editor

Tags: wordpress, svg

I'm trying to insert an inline SVG of a US map in a Wordpress post. A test page where it's been inserted into the post as an HTML block with some light CSS is here: http://thepostrider.com/test-post/

When I edit it in the Gutenberg editor I can see the SVG and all, but on preview/publish nothing. It's clearly there in the code if you inspect the element on that published page but cannot for the life of me get it to manifest in the post. Historically I've gotten around this by building out custom pages and inserting SVGs into php files, but I do need to start building out this kind of thing in individual posts now too; so I would love some advice.

Comment: You should make a shortcode for your SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the HTML source:

```
<g id="g5">
    <path id="HI" data-info="<div>State: Hawaii</div><div>Capital: Honolulu</div>&#8221;
    fill=&#8221;#D3D3D3&#8243; d=&#8221;M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9
    l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6
    l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9
    l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z
    M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8
    l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z&#8221;/>
    ... etc ...
```

It looks to me like Wordpress has converted all your quotation marks into smart quotes (`&#8221;` and `&#8243;`). That's not going to help.

You would be better off uploading the SVG file as an image and inserting it that way. (You may need to install additional plugins to do this, as Wordpress won't allow SVG uploads in its default state.)

---

*By the way, the next time you ask a question about code or markup, please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and insert it directly into your question. Links to code on other sites are liable to break, making your question useless for others. Thanks.*